# editorconfig file for c# language rules doesn't trigger build failure

Tags: c#, editorconfig

I have this simple Program.cs file:

```
namespace SampleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static int field;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Test();
        }

        public static void Test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(field);
        }
    }
}
```

and the following naming rule in my .editorconfig file:

```
dotnet_naming_rule.private_or_internal_field_should_be_underscore.severity = error
dotnet_naming_rule.private_or_internal_field_should_be_underscore.symbols = private_or_internal_field
dotnet_naming_rule.private_or_internal_field_should_be_underscore.style = underscore
```

In my IDE I indeed see an error regarding the private field "field", saying:

Error   IDE1006 Naming rule violation: Missing prefix: '_'

and it does appear in my errors list.

When I try to build and run the program, it's done successfully even though the severity was marked as an error.

I also made sure to include this line:

dotnet_diagnostic.IDE1006.severity = error

in my editorconfig file, but steel it's being compiled and run successfully.

This is all the potential fixes I found on the internet but none of them seems to solve my issue.

Comment: I also added this line: <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>true</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild> to my csproj file, but with no success

Comment: You can't do it, `.editorconfig` is, as the name implies, a config file for the *editor* (ie, VS, VS Code, Rider etc), not for the compiler. That's why the errors you're getting are `IDE...` errors, not `CA...` errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your issue CAN be solved - compilation is handled by the compiler, editorconfig is for the editor. I am not sure the compiler has ANY knowledge about it. If it would - that would make the compiler more complex and - well - tie it up with functionality it does not need. But it would be nice.

To get it to work with dotnet build - https://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2020/07/08/editorconfig-msbuild.html indicates there is a code analyzer you can put in manually. All pretty old, though. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/52051 talks about this with Roslyn - (Roslyn code analyzers) indicating it was at least on the dotnet team visibility.

You may want to investigate around https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/60620 - and the linked issues there. And indicate more information about your environment - that seems to be an issue that is ongoing, so what version of the toolset may change the behavious.